# get object on ListView Tappedevent

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview that is being populated from an SQLite DB. For that listview have constructed a method for handling when a listview element is being tapped:

xaml cell:

```
<ListView x:Name="CalculationListview" ItemsSource="{Binding Calculation}" HasUnevenRows="true" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" Refreshing="Handle_Refreshing">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Tapped="Handle_Tapped">
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" />
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Qty}">
                    </Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Note}">
                    </Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}">
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

c#

```
async void Handle_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var viewCellSelected = sender as MenuItem;
    var calculation = viewCellSelected?.BindingContext as Calculation;

    var page = new ViewSaved(calculation);
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
}
```

As you can see, I want to retrieve the object `Calculation` from the given listview element and send the object to a new view named `ViewSaved`.

Unfortunately, my variable `calculation` remains null and I get an exception when I send the empty object to my new view.

I suspect that `sender as MenuItem;` is the issue.

Comment: please show the relevant code/xaml for the cell and it's bindings

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: When you debug this, does `viewCellSelected` come back as null?

Comment: `ViewCellSelected` comes back as null yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of putting the `Tapped` handler on the `ViewCell`, either use the `ListView's` `ItemTapped` or `ItemSelected` methods

```
void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
      var item = (Calculation)i.Item;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it did the job! Can you perhaps elaborate on the difference?